# Asp.net WebApi OData V4 problems with nested $expands

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a `OData V4` over `Asp.net WebApi` (`OWIN`).

Everything works great, except when I try to query a 4-level `$expand`.

My query looks like:

```
http://domain/entity1($expand=entity2($expand=entity3($expand=entity4)))
```

I don't get any error, but the last expand isn't projected in my response.

More info:

1. I've set the `MaxExpandDepth` to 10.
2. All my Entities are `EntitySets`.
3. I'm using the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`.
4. I've opened an SQL-profiler and could see that the query (and the result) is correct. It's some filter that occurs after the query is executed.
5. I've searched the web and didn't find anything suitable.
6. I've tried different entity 4 level `$expands` and they didn't work as well.

**Edit:**

I've overridden the `OnActionExecuted`:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

    var objectContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
    var val = objectContent.Value;

    var t = Type.GetType("System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandWrapperConverter, System.Web.OData");
    var jc = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as JsonConverter;
    var jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    jss.Converters.Add(jc);

    var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(val, jss);
 }
```

The serialized value contains entity4.

I still have no idea what component removes entity4 in the pipe.

**Edit #2:**

I've create an adapter over `DefaultODataSerializerProvider` and over all the other `ODataEdmTypeSerializer's`. I see that during the process the `$expand` for entity4 exists and when the `ODataResourceSerializer.CreateNavigationLink` method  is called on that navigationProperty (entity4) then it returns null.

I've jumped into the source code and I could see that the `SerializerContext.Items` doesn't include the entity4 inside it's items and the `SerializerContext.NavigationSource` is null.

To be specific with versions, I'm using `System.Web.OData, Version=6.1.0.10907`.

Comment: How do you se the MaxExpandDepth ?  could you show us the code of the controller?

Comment: @J.Loscos - Inside the `EnableQueryAttribute` that is placed above the `Get` methods. I know that I'm doing it correct since I needed to modify the value to 3 in the past due to a MaxDepth not supported exception.

Comment: What version of Microsoft.AspNet.OData are you using ? I did a quick test with the 6.1.0 version and a 4 level expand query worked without any problems

Comment: @J.Loscos - Yes, I'm using 6.1.0. I'm using ILSpy trying to tackle the problem. As I said before, The SQL that is produced returns the 4th level and so does the IQueryable that is produced after calling the `ApplyQuery` method inside the `EnableQueryAttribute`.

Comment: @J.Loscos - can you plz paste here the odata.context on your successful 4 level $expand response?

Comment: My odata.context is : `"@odata.context":"http://localhost:18746/odata/$metadata#Entity1"` 
My query is odata/Entity1?$expand=Entity2($expand=Entity3($expand=Entity4))

Comment: @J.Loscos - Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I noticed the problem was due to the fact that my navigation property was of type `EdmUnknownEntitySet` and the navigation property lookup returns null (source code attached with an evil TODO..):

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds the entity set that a navigation property targets.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="property">The navigation property.</param>
/// <returns>The entity set that the navigation propertion targets, or null if no such entity set exists.</returns>
/// TODO: change null logic to using UnknownEntitySet
public override IEdmNavigationSource FindNavigationTarget(IEdmNavigationProperty property)
{
    return null;
}
```

So I understood my problem was with the `EdmUnknownEntitySet`.

I digged into the code and saw that I needed to add the `ContainedAttribute` to the my navigation properties.

Since my solution is kind of a Generic repository, I've added it in the Startup for All navigation properties:

```
builder.OnModelCreating = mb => mb.StructuralTypes.SelectMany(s => s.NavigationProperties
            .Where(np => np.Multiplicity == EdmMultiplicity.Many)).Distinct().ForEach(np => np.Contained());

//......

var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
```